# Can't recognise this sequence of square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I've been wondering about this for a while but can't find out the following:

$$\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{0} + \sqrt{1}}+\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2}}+\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}}+ \dots +\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{9999} + \sqrt{10000}}$$

I'm a noob but still some explanation would be cool. I can't seem to catch the sequence.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$ by ${\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}$. And happy days are here again.

Comment: **Hint:** Multiply each $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}$ by $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ above and below.

Comment: It's good to see that GMTA, but André gets the nod for his "happy days" comment. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In french it is called the *conjugué*, conjugate in english.  Multiply each fraction by it ot remove the square root in the denominator.
\begin{equation}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{0}+\sqrt{1}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{0}+\sqrt{1}}\times \dfrac{\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{0}}{\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{0}}= \dfrac{\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{0}}{1}
\end{equation}
Apply the same thing to every fraction and see what you'll have.

edit : thanks @smci for the english term and @Clement C. for the typo.

Comment: You got there first! +1.

Comment: Wohooo! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Chinny84 your anwer is more complete than mine

Comment: Ha but a complete answer wasn't necessary in this case ;)!

Comment: and *'conjugate'* in English

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n} +\sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{\sqrt{n} -\sqrt{n+1}}{(\sqrt{n} +\sqrt{n+1})(\sqrt{n} -\sqrt{n+1})}
$$
The denominator becomes
$$
(\sqrt{n} +\sqrt{n+1})(\sqrt{n} -\sqrt{n+1}) = n -n -1 = -1
$$
Thus the sum becomes
$$
-\sum_{n=0}^k \sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}
$$
Which is a telescope sum.

Answer (score 0):

Hint
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{a+1}}=\sqrt{a+1}-\sqrt{a}$$